# JBoss, IntelliJ IDEA, deploy exploded ear, subdeployment doesn't work

Tags: java, intellij-idea, deployment, jboss, hotswap

Good morning

I'm evaluating Intellij IDEA for my new employer, but I can't get our J2EE project up
and running for exploded artifacts. Everything works just fine when I deploy it
as archives, but it doesn't work when I try it exploded. And for "Hot Swapping",
for example when I change .jsp or java classes it's recommended to use exploded
artifacts.
My .ear contains two other web archives, and that seems to be the problem:
- .ear
-- .jar
-- .war
-- lib/
-- META-INF/

the .jar file contains EJBs
the .war file contains all Servlets (for example the Login page)

When I deploy the .ear as an exploded artifact jboss starts just fine, but
as it looks, it doesnt deploy the two archives inside. The log output is pretty
short und also in the management console of jboss I don't see the two archives
deployed under .ear. I tried many different preferences for the .ear.exploded
artifact but I can't get it to run.
I'm not sure if it's an Intellij IDEA problem or a Jboss problem.

Here is the software we use:
- Intellij IDEA 14.1.4
- jdk 1.7.0_79
- JBoss EAP 6.4
- Maven 3.3.3

Would be great to get some help, because I like Intellij IDEA. ;)

Comment: Hello 
I have same issue and I am not still being able to figure it out
Can you please help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After getting in touch with the jetbrains support I was able to solve my issue.
The exploaded folder has to have the correct extension.
So add the extension for the exploaded artifact.

`Project Structure -> Artifacts -> Select exploaded Artifact -> Add under Output directory the extension. (In my case ".ear")`

Then Jboss will treat it like a ear.

Thanx for reading my post.

Comment: I don't see `Output directory`, could you please post a screenshot where it's located in the "Artifacts" window?